# Spring Cloud Data Flow Python Script Processor does not work

Tags: python, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I am trying to build a simple stream pipeline using file | script  | file
I choose python as scripting language
How do I write long python scripts in the Data Flow UI ?
The code that I want to execute by giving in the UI :

```
def input():
    return "Pre" + payload;

def output():
    return payload + "Post";

result = locals()[channel]()
```

What is the convention ?

I am getting TokenizationError:UnExpectedChar errors. If try to escape spacial characters I am getting splitter exceptions during the execution

[See the Error and PipeLine On Data Flow UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I0mf.jpg)
[Adding Python Script Here as it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUFPa.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the samples [here](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/polyglot/) which show how you can use python apps inside SCDF stream/task